# Microsoft band 2: UV sensor in background

Tags: android, microsoft-band

We are working on a new microsoft band app that measures your overall UV exposure combining it with vitamin d synthesi and tracking.

This would require for the uv sensor to work in background, but I can't seem to find a way to do it, is it possible to set manually the uv sensor refresh/usage rate?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you be more specific about what your looking to do, or what you've already tried?  Sensor subscriptions via the Band SDK work the same way whether used in the foreground or background.  If you're asking how to create a background task on Android (from which you can then subscribe to the sensor), then that's an entirely different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Phil Hoff said in his comment, there is no foreground and background mode in the Band SDK, and you can't set the UV sensor refresh rate either.

What you're probably looking for is how to keep the connection alive and receive data from the sensors when your (Android-?) app is not in the foreground. If you meant this, then what you should look at is [**Foreground Service in Android**](http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/android-foreground-service-example-tutorial/).